# A non-Ajax login page

Tags: feature-request, login, authentication, stack-exchange-openid

Think it or not, there are still people that use dial-up. Also the GPRS service on most operators is not so fast.

It's almost impossible to use dial-up or GPRS to login using your stack exchange profile; The "Loading" picture appears but the email/password fields never load.

Please add a non-ajax log-in page for users with slow connections.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're talking about our OpenID provider, if so this already exists.  You can go directly to the provider here: https://openid.stackexchange.com/ and click login.

Then, to login to our sites, just click the "login with Stack Exchange" option (same as before) and you'll no need to enter your name/password, sine you're already authenticated to the provider.